# Make button effect without button tag

Tags: html, css, button

How to make a button border effect like on the button below without the typical button tag? How to make a button border effect like on the button below without the typical button tag?How to make a button border effect like on the button below without the typical button tag?How to make a button border effect like on the button below without the typical button tag?

```css
span#mustBeEffectHowAsfromTypicalButton {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: rgb(89, 89, 89);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 41%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 42%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1) 41%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 42%);
    background: linear-gradient(352deg, rgba(189, 189, 189, 1) 51%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 1) 51%);
}

.myButton>span:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 12px;
}

.myButton:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: calc(100% - 9px);
    height: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
    border-radius: 16px;
}


.myButton {
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease;
    -o-transition: 0.2s all ease;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
    font-family: RobotoCondensed-Light;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: linear-gradient(orange, lightorange);
    border-radius: 16px;
    z-index: 3;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.myButton:hover {
    color: white;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3D94F6, #1E62D0);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3D94F6, #1E62D0);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3D94F6, #1E62D0);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3D94F6, #1E62D0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3D94F6, #1E62D0);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0px white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

span.myButton>span:nth-child(3) {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 210%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 1px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}

span.myButton:hover span#highlight {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<span id="mustBeEffectHowAsfromTypicalButton">
<span  class="myButton"  >
<span  id="highlight"> </span>
<span id="highlight">BUTTON use SPAN TAG</span>
<span id="highlight"></span>
</span>
</span>

<Br><Br>


<button class="myButton" style="height: 45px;">

<span  id="highlight"> </span>
<span id="highlight">BUTTON use BUTTON TAG</span>
<span id="highlight"></span>
</button>
```

[button for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKefn.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you can use css class to do so

```
.btn {
      background: #3B81F6;
      color: #fff;
      padding; 10px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      font-size: 20px;
  }

.btn:active {
   box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(28, 101, 201, 0.25);
}
or
.btn:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(28, 101, 201, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: You have provided a normal button class, but it is not a solution to the problem unfortunately.